# For positive, decreasing $a_n$, must $a_n=O(1/n)$ for the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ to converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $a_n$ is a sequence of decreasing positive numbers, must $a_n=O(1/n)$ for the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$  to converge? I think it's true but a proof eludes me. My ideas so far:

Suppose it's not true, then for all $C>0$ and for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $n \geq N$ such that $a_n>C/N$. Take $C=1$. Let $n_k$ be a sequence such that $a_{n_k}>1/n_k$.

- If the $n_k$ are close together then the series clearly won't converge (since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/n$ diverges)
- If the $n_k$ are all say a constant $M$ apart, so $n_k=Mk$, then the series will diverge since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/a_n \geq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} M \cdot(1/Mk)=\infty$
- If the $n_k$ are rapidly getting further and further apart then
  $$\sum_{n=1}^{n_k} =\sum_{n=1}^{n_1} a_n + \sum_{n=n_1}^{n_2} a_n +...+\sum_{n=n_{k-1}}^{n_k} a_n \geq \frac{n_1}{n_1}+\frac{n_2-n_1}{n_2}+....+\frac{n_k-n_{k-1}}{n_k} \approx k. $$

So these three cases lead me to believe it is true but I don't know how to prove it. Any help would be appreciated. It seems like there should be a simple proof of this.

Comment: What about $a_n=\frac1{\sqrt n}\cdot[\text{$n$ is a power of $2$}]$ ? EDIT: I missed "non-decreasing".

Comment: @YvesDaoust Technically, $a_{n}=\frac{1}{n^{2}}$ is $O\left(1/n\right)$ since $\frac{1}{n^{2}}\leq \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\geq1$, and the series $\sum\frac{1}{n^{2}}$ converges.

Comment: @Brian: you are right. I need some rest.

Comment: @YvesDaoust OP was asking must $|a_{n}|\leq \frac{k}{n}$ for some positive k in some tail of a convergent series with the $a_{n}$ decreasing. Restated once again for clarity: If the series converges and $a_{n}$ is decreasing, then $|a_{n}|\leq \frac{k}{n}$ for some positive k in some tail of the sequence $a_{n}$. At least that is how I am reading the question as currently stated.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, one even has $a_n=o(1/n)$ (if $a_n$ is **positive decreasing**). Indeed, let $k$ be the integer part of $n/2$: then $\sum_{i=k}^{n}{a_i} \rightarrow 0$, and $0\leq \frac{na_n}{2} \leq (n-k+1){a_n} \leq \sum_{i=k}^n{a_i}$, so it follows $na_n \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: What about $a_n=\frac1{\sqrt n}\cdot[\text{$n$ is a power of $2$}]$ ? (Nevermind after the edit.)

Comment: The OP states that $a_n$ must be decreasing.

Comment: ahhhh sorry, missed that

Comment: Nice proof, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assume the sum converges to $L>0$ and that $a_n\neq O(1/n)$. Then there are infinite natural numbers $\{N_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ such that

$$a_{N_k}>\frac{2L}{N_k}$$

But then for any of the naturals in this sequence (denoted just by $N$ at this point)

$$L=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n>\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n\geq \sum_{n=1}^{N}a_{N}>\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{2L}{N}=N\frac{2L}{N}=2L$$

Since this is a contradiction, we conclude $a_n=O(1/n)$$

Comment: No, there are no infinite natural numbers! Every natural number is finite. There are _infinitely many_ natural numbers such that etc.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong, but wouldn't $a_1=2$, $a_n=\sqrt{a_{n-1}}$ for all n>1 violate your conjecture?

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ doesn't seem to converge here, though?

Comment: The wording of the question maybe tripped you up you can restate the question as an if then statement like so: If the series converges and $a_{n}$ is decreasing, then $|a_{n}|\leq \frac{k}{n}$ for some positive k in some tail of the sequence $a_{n}$. At least that is how I am reading the question as currently stated.