# If $\{a_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a set of positive numbers s.t $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_n< \infty$, can we rearrange them so that $a_n=o(1/n)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given a set $\{a_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of positive numbers such that $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_n< \infty$, is there a bijection $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_{f(n)}=o(1/n)$? It's true that if $a_n$ is a positive decreasing sequence such that $\sum_{n \in  \mathbb{N}} a_n < \infty$ then we must have $a_n=o(1/n)$ (see: [For positive, decreasing $a_n$, must $a_n=O(1/n)$ for the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ to converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4084375/for-positive-decreasing-a-n-must-a-n-o1-n-for-the-series-sum-n-1-i/4084383#4084383)), but the problem is that we can't necessary write $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ as a decreasing sequence. Unfortunately, I'm not sure where to begin with proving this or coming up with a counter example. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, as $a_n \rightarrow 0$ and is positive, you actually *can* find an ordering of $a_n$.

Comment: First, it's not $f(a_n)$, it's $a_{f(n)}$. Second, it is enough to prove that there exists a bijection $f$ such that $(a_{f(n)})$ is nonincreasing.

Comment: Ah okay, I can see that is true (and how to prove it). Cheers!

Comment: I've changed it D. Thomine, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one can rearrange $a_n$ so that it is decreasing (non - increasing).

Then $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}n\cdot a_n = 0$, since
$\sum_{k =n}^{2n} a_k >= n\cdot a_{2n}$ and convergences of the series implies
that $\sum_{k =n}^{2n} a_k$ tends to $0$.

Comment: This seems to work because you can indeed rearrange in a nonincreasing ordering when the numbers are all positive. The argument would fail if there could be infinitely many indices $n$ such that $a_n=0$, even though the conclusion would still be correct in that case (just sequentially change the $k$th value that is zero to $1/2^k$ and redo the above argument).